# Make one all.js from various js files

Tags: javascript

I am making a website using PHP. I have various Javascript snippets in various pages and various Javascript files. I want to put them all in one .js file. How can I do that?

Comment: Um... copy and paste all of it into one .js file?

Answer (score 2):

Copy them all into one file, in the order they were included within document.

If they were written correctly, there should be no problems. But there may be problems regarding some conflicts (like names of the variables) or cases, when the script was not meant to be executed on all pages (eg. assumes some container exists within HTML, but this container is only on some pages - thus on other pages the script may throw some errors or behave inappropriately).

Answer (score 0):

With PHP you could just make a faux-javascript file, e.g. `js.php` and then include all the js files like:

```
<?php

    include('foo.js');
    include('bar.js');
```

Then reference this file from the main php page's html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js.php"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is by inline js as

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 <?php
  include "one.js";
  include "two.js";
 ?>
</script>
```

I also try to reduce js, css and use image sprite for background to reduce browser header requests.